# Can an OSX server handle windows account administration and file storage?

Tags: windows, macos, osx-mountain-lion, osx-server

I want a server and I have a contract with a business to set up a network with the current systems and a new Mac Pro.

I have used OS X server before but not for a while so I need to know: Can I set up the network with Windows PCs and have the Mac Pro do user administration? Can the users use the Mac Pro for a networked drive to store there data on (they bought the Mac Pro with the hard drive bays full)?

Can any one give me advice on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Network drive: Yes, OS X Server's file sharing provides both SMB (for Windows clients) and AFP (for OS X clients) protocols. (The 10.7 and 10.8 versions also provide WebDAV service, primarily for iOS clients.)

User administration: No, Windows computers pretty much only support user admin by Active Directory, and OS X Server doesn't provide that. Apple uses a similar-but-incompatible system for network-based user management called Open Directory. If you need to manage users on Windows clients, go with a Windows server.

Comment: What do you recomend